# Puppet: Cannot find class cron

Tags: puppet, cron

I'm using Puppet 3.4.3.

I'm trying to use the cron type to manage cron jobs (as documented here: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html). However, any time I try and run my configuration:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class cron for app on node app

As far as I can tell, the documentation is referencing and inbuilt type, and I shouldn't have to include any modules or download anything extra? Is the minimum version for the cron type higher than 3.4.3?

It's not a problem with my individual configuration, as even the logrotate example given on the documentation page fails with the same error message.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** Here is the code i'm using:

```
cron { laravelschedule:
        command => "php /var/www/sociaspire/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1",
        user => www-data,
        hour => '*',
        minute => '*',
        month => '*',
        monthday => '*',
        week => '*',  
}
```

**Edit:** Output from `ls -ltr`:

```
total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7357 Aug 20 10:37 sociaspire-testing.pp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6481 Aug 20 10:37 sociaspire.pp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3128 Aug 20 10:37 sociaspire-lb.pp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3074 Aug 20 10:37 sociaspire-db.pp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8195 Sep 10 13:23 sociaspire-standalone.pp
```

Output from `tree -f`:

```
.
├── ./classes
│   └── ./classes/sociaspire-standalone.pp
└── ./site.pp
```

Comment: I call syntax error. Please add a code excerpt to your question to illustrate how you try and implement the cron type.

Comment: quote the resource title laravelschedule should be "laravelschedule"

Comment: @c4f4t0r I tried both variations of quoted and unquoted to no avail. The PuppetLabs reference also uses unquoted resource titles.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found is to use a cron module (specifically: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/torrancew/cron).

Syntax is very similar but this module seems to work for me where Puppet's inbuilt type didn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem, but I cannot write the whole code in a comment, using puppet-lint you can see if your code style is correct

This is the result checking your code style.

```
puppet-lint /home/user01/programming/puppet/bad.pp
WARNING: double quoted string containing no variables on line 2
ERROR: trailing whitespace found on line 8
WARNING: line has more than 80 characters on line 2
WARNING: indentation of => is not properly aligned on line 2
WARNING: indentation of => is not properly aligned on line 3
WARNING: indentation of => is not properly aligned on line 4
WARNING: indentation of => is not properly aligned on line 5
WARNING: indentation of => is not properly aligned on line 6
WARNING: indentation of => is not properly aligned on line 8
WARNING: unquoted resource title on line 1
```

As you can see above, in line one, the resource title need to be quoted.

You can fix your code using `puppet-lint -f /home/user01/programming/puppet/bad.pp` Now if you run again `puppet-lint /home/user01/programming/puppet/bad.pp` you will see no errors and wornings

Looking the puppetlabs doc `https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#cron` where the example of `cron provider` the resource title is quoted with single quote if you don't have a variabile in the resource title, the `week` attribute need to be `weekday`